# Error in random function

Tags: c, random, cuda, syntax-error

I have error my code - I get the  error."**error: expected a ")".**

this error comes becuse of **random_ints function**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>


#define N (1024*1024)
#define M (1000000)

void random_ints(int *a, int N)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    a[i] = rand() %5000;
}


__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
        c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];
    }


    int main(void) {
    int *a, *b, *c;     // host copies of a, b, c
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;   // device copies of a, b, c
    int size = N * sizeof(int);

    // Alloc space for device copies of a, b, c
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size);

    // Alloc space for host copies of a, b, c and setup input values
    a = (int *)malloc(size); random_ints(a, N);
    b = (int *)malloc(size); random_ints(b, N);
    c = (int *)malloc(size);
        // Copy inputs to device
        cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        // Launch add() kernel on GPU with N blocks
        add<<<N,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);

        // Copy result back to host
        cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        // Cleanup
        free(a); free(b); free(c);
        cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);
        return 0;
    }
```

is there any header required for this function or is only error in syntax?

Comment: I strongly suggest using `static const int N = ...` instead of `#define N ...` for numeric constants. Using defines can easily lead to hard-to-understand errors in location you least expect.

Comment: Assuming *"this error comes becuse of random_ints function"* is accurate, `man 3 rand` tells you to use `#include <stdlib.h>`. It looks like you have the right header. It appears you have a typo in the function. The function parameter is ***`N`***, but you used ***`M`*** in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Consider how `random_ints` would be defined after the `#define` macros are interpreted:

```
void random_ints(int *a, int (1024*1024))
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    a[i] = rand() %5000;
}
```

Clearly, you cannot specify a numeric literal in a function's declaration like this.

It seems as though the second parameter should be the array's size. You can call it `n` to avoid colliding with `N`:

```
void random_ints(int *a, int n)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       a[i] = rand() %5000;
}
```